# How can a probability distribution work with the subset of the support?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

[Discrete Distributions](http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Discrete.html)

[image]

1. What is $A$?
2. Why is $\sum_ {x \in A} f(x) = \Bbb P (X \in A), \; A \subseteq S$, in case of a random variable $X$?
3. If $\Omega$ is the sample space and $S$ is the support of the random variable $X$, where does $A$ come from?
4. Is the property $\sum_ {x \in A} f(x) = \Bbb P (X \in A), \; A \subseteq S$ really necessary to define a distribution function?

Please, explain with a simple practical example (like rolling a die, etc.).

Comment: If you want help it's better to make your question self-contained instead of asking people to read an entire lesson on discrete distributions.

Comment: @dsaxton, done.

Comment: A is just some subset of S, in fact everything in the link holds if A = S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $A$ is any old measurable subset of $S$. (It looks like in this context, $S$ is countable, in which case you can use its power set as a σ-algebra and hence $A$ can be any subset of $S$ at all.)
2. This isn't true for all random variables, but it is for discrete random variables. This follows from one of the definitional properties of measures, which is that they're countably additive.
3. $S$ isn't the support of $X$. It's the codomain of $X$.
4. (I guess that by "distribution function" you mean "probability density function".) No. For example, this equation fails for the PDF of the standard normal distribution.